# querying server about remotely connected machine names

Tags: windows, remote-access

I'm looking to identify exactly one piece of information, however oddly hard to obtain:

How do I find out what machine names are connected to a certain server remotely (under windows)? I tried my luck with `quser`, `qwinsta` and powershell scripts without success.

Retracing the %clientname% environmental variable is not an option for me as within the java environment it is called from, it reports an old value.

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know of these free tools which might help :

[**TSListUsers**](http://home.fnal.gov/~jklemenc/tslistusers.html)

> command line utility to list both the
>   currently connected and disconnected
>   users, hostname, IP address and RDP
>   session number on either the local or
>   a remote Windows Terminal Server/RDP
>   Server.
>
> To list the users, you need to have the following abilities:
>
> - NetBios access to the server
> - Permissions allowing you to Query RDP session information (if you can log into the TS, you should have this by default)
> - Terminal Services/RDP should be running on the target host

---

A useful but simpler tool is
[psloggedon](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/psloggedon) :

[image: psloggedon]

---

For Terminal Server sessions, a useful tool will be the free
[LazyTS](http://www.lazywinadmin.com/2014/10/powershell-gui-lazyts-terminal-services.html)
(Terminal Services Management)
for PowerShell GUI.

---

A pure PowerShell solution assumes that the logged-on users are using the
Explorer desktop shell (not [custom shell](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/customize/enterprise/shell-launcher)).
It is much easier to count the instances of the `explorer.exe` process
and find their owners, as in
[this script](https://p0w3rsh3ll.wordpress.com/2012/02/03/get-logged-on-users/) :

```
$explorerprocesses = @(Get-WmiObject -Query "Select * FROM Win32_Process WHERE Name='explorer.exe'" -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue)
if ($explorerprocesses.Count -eq 0)
{
    "No explorer process found / Nobody interactively logged on"
} else {
    foreach ($i in $explorerprocesses)
    {
        $Username = $i.GetOwner().User
        $Domain = $i.GetOwner().Domain
        $Domain + "\" + $Username + " logged on since: " + ($i.ConvertToDateTime($i.CreationDate))
    }
}
```

A simpler
[approach](https://richardspowershellblog.wordpress.com/2012/01/17/get-the-logged-on-users/)
using the `Win32_LogonSession` class
also works, but tends to give more results than expected :

```
function get-logedonuser {            
param (            
 [string]$computername = $env:COMPUTERNAME            
)            
Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_LogonSession -ComputerName $computername |            
foreach {            
 $data = $_            

 $id = $data.__RELPATH -replace """", "'"            
 $q = "ASSOCIATORS OF {$id} WHERE ResultClass = Win32_Account"            
 Get-WmiObject -ComputerName $computername -Query $q |            
 select @{N="User";E={$($_.Caption)}},             
 @{N="LogonTime";E={$data.ConvertToDateTime($data.StartTime)}}            
}            
}
```

Comment: do any of these come with standard windows server installs?

Comment: These are third-party products.  The first two are closed-source, but LazyTS is an open-source PowerShell script which uses the open-source [Cassia](https://github.com/ng-pe/cassia) .NET Terminal Services library

Comment: I'm looking for a default windows function =/

Comment: You could use a pure PowerShell script. I have added a couple of such scripts.