# Active directory and folder access

Tags: active-directory

Allow Active Directory userA to access folderA on Virtual Machine, when logged from computerA. Restrict access to same user and same folder, when logged from computerB. Is this possible? How?

Comment: No, this is not possible straight-forward as the folder permissions can be assigned on account-based approach only. But you can develop a custom script that runs at logon of VM and adds deny permission to a specific folder and removes it at logoff if connected from specific PC. Deny prevails over allow permissions. So allow permissions always stay untouched.

Comment: Thanks! Any directions as where to look the matter of custom scripts on Hyper-V? I am a complete newbie.

Comment: It's a matter of googling. The script is not for Hyper-V, it's just a regular Windows script (bat, vbs, powershell). i don't think that anyone was had such task before, so you most probably will need to craft it yourself combining of different found scripts. Like google how to determine from which PC user got connected in RDP session. Then google how to assign permissions on the folder (there are many ways). When create if () {} then {} wrapper for that. Finally combine in one and add to task scheduler.

Comment: The first answer I found for you in a few seconds :) https://superuser.com/questions/1268007/querying-server-about-remotely-connected-machine-names

Comment: Sorry to come back to the subject. I notice that in folder properties, under the SECURITY tab, and ADVANCED option, we can add a condition to limit the access of a principal. There is the option to choose DEVICE - GROUP .... etc. I tried putting computerB to a Group of AD and then writing a conditional like : Device Group Not Member of Any MyCustom Group. The result is that I always get blocked from access regardless of the computer I am logged into

Comment: I was under impression you were accessing VM via RDP from different machines since you mentioned Hyper-V. If you are accessing shared folder not via RDP but via SMB network share - this is a different story. Take a note that Conditional expressions are not compatible with Win7 clients and non-domain clients. 

Also it will not work out-of-box, first you need to deploy DAC policies and configure them,  make your clients claim-aware, after which you can apply it to the folder. Refer to https://www.lepide.com/blog/dynamic-access-control-for-file-server-1/ and article 2nd part